# Synchronized threads behaviour

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a **Cell class** representing a single value and **swapThread class** whose run method just call the method **swapValue()** in Cell.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    Cell c1 = new Cell(15);
    Cell c2 = new Cell(23);

    Thread t1 = new swapThread(c1, c2);
    Thread t2 = new swapThread(c2, c1);

    t1.start();
    t2.start();
}
```

**class Cell**:

```
class Cell {
private static int counter = 0;
private int value, id;

public Cell(int v) {
    value = v;
    id = counter++;
}

synchronized int getValue() {
    return value;
}

synchronized void setValue(int v) {
    value = v;
}

void swapValue(Cell other) {

    int t = getValue();
    System.out.println("Swapping " + t);
    int v = other.getValue();
    System.out.println("with " + v);
    setValue(v);
    other.setValue(t);

    System.out.println("Cell is now " + getValue());
    System.out.println("Cell was " + other.getValue());
}

}
```

and **class swapThread**:

```
class swapThread extends Thread {
Cell cell, othercell;

public swapThread(Cell c, Cell oc) {
    cell = c;
    othercell = oc;
}

public void run() {

    cell.swapValue(othercell);

}
}
```

**Usual output:**

```
Swapping 15
Swapping 23
with 23
with 15
Cell is now 23
Cell is now 15
Cell was 15
Cell was 23
```

I can just wait for the thread1 to finish with **Thread.join()** in the main method but is there a way to avoid that by changing the synchronized methods.

Comment: in `swapValue()`, before swapping, you need first to acquire lock on both cells (`this` and `other`) to perform operation atomically.

Comment: Swapping is not atomic as per your implementation.

Comment: Is there a way to solve the problem without inrtoducing any locking objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve serial execution of `swapValues()` by making this method static and synchronized:

```
static synchronized void swapValues(Cell c1, Cell c2) {

    int t = c1.getValue();
    System.out.println("Swapping " + t);
    int v = c2.getValue();
    System.out.println("with " + v);
    c1.setValue(v);
    c2.setValue(t);

    System.out.println("Cell is now " + c1.getValue());
    System.out.println("Cell was " + c2.getValue());
}
```

Thus, you synchronize it on `Cell.class`, making `swapValues()` to be performed sequentially.

Notice, now you need to pass 2 cells in it:

```
public void run() {
    Cell.swapValues(cell, othercell);
}
```

Comment: I guess it is the static keyword that solves that. Am I correct?

Comment: Non-static synchronized methods are synchronized on intrinsic lock of given *instance* (i.e. `cell` or `othercell`--two different objects have two locks that can be acquired in parallel). Static synchronized methods are synchronized by *class* (i. e. `Cell.class`--both `swapValues()` calls must acquire the same lock, so they execute serially).

Comment: I just noticed that it always swaps 15 and 23 twice and forgets about the vice versa.

Comment: Because first: **c1 as cell** =15,  **c2 as othercell** =23. After swap: c1=23, c2=15. Then you swap **c2 as cell** (=15) and **c1 as othercell** (=23)